# Turn-Based Board Game is Freezing

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

We have a turn-based board game which developing backend side in Java 1.8

We got a problem in game. Sometimes our process start to take too long, but we didn't any solution or any tool to track the problem. We have a machine with 40 cores, and works 140 threads which thread count of reserved for game playing is 24. Game threads is working actively and concurrently so I mean all game threads are in the RUNNING state when happing long process. In the long process situation our game ai calculates any hand under 40 ms, but when happening long process this duration reaches 300-400 ms. **There is no deadlock**

We are using G1GC as garbage collector that was set GC's config up according to our requirements. We have a lot of thread dump but almost all of them is different each other. Do you have any idea to find solution out or any tool to realize that which situation causes the problem ?

Comment: Enable GC logging to see if the problem is GC pauses and consider running some profiling. If this only happens in production, then you'd need to use sampling-based profiling or the performance impact would probably be too big.

Comment: Actually GC logs are enabled and we didn't encounter any reasons for this situation.  the reason why this is catching just in production is that there is no many player in order to cause that in development environment. But mostly same things are available for development environment.

Comment: That’s an impressive machine to play a board game. But maybe, you forgot to mention that it is a server for multiple players (how many)? Or is there another reason for using such hardware? What are the other 116 threads doing? And why is a max response time of 400 ms a problem, for a *turn-based board game*?

Comment: At evening there are mostly 10K concurrent user in the server. Other threads works on other service like handling exception, scanning server situation that is there any thing wrong, some of them is regarding our service provider. But any problem doesn't happening in these kind of thread, just specific threads which works our game play. 

Long process time like 400ms causes that prevents quickly response time, so our game starts to be freezing and occur worse user experiments

Comment: @Holger: I think finding out *why* one of them needs 400ms is pretty much the point of this question.

Comment: you are right, but when I try to work ai by providing same game requirements, never responds above 40 ms. How can I do to observe thread stack instantly? when trying to take thread dump, I don't catch anything

Comment: Didn't you read my suggestion to attach a (sampling based) profiler to your JVM?

Comment: @JoachimSauer but that was not my question. I asked why this is a problem in a *turn based* game that doesn’t need real time response times.

Comment: @Holger: Oh, I see, I misread your comment then. Having played a couple of board games online I can say that 400ms response time to some interaction can be a problem and make the whole thing feel very unresponsive. This isn't necessarily the "do this whole turn" call.

Comment: @SAMETUZUN How do these 24 game threads relate to the 10k concurrent users? Are they all playing on the same board that the game is calculating for? There are too little information. Besides that, it’s perfectly possible to have an algorithm which requires 40 ms in one scenario and 400 ms in a different scenario. Take a sort algorithm, for example. Even sorting the same objects but having a different start order can take a significantly different time.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that’s why we need more information. When it is about the interaction other than “next turn”, it can be annoying, but that wouldn’t fit to the mentioned “10k users”, as then, even 40 ms per action would be a problem, when it blocks one of the 24 threads.

Comment: First of all, I have to point out that our problem is that all of the threads playing the game switch to the RUNNING position at once, and after a while they self-correct, then the same cycle repeats again after a while. What we want to do is to examine the movements of the threads instantly and find the piece of code or method that caused this, because we cannot catch them with thread dump. You mentioned above that **sampling profiler** can be done for this, is there a tool you can recommend for this?

Comment: This looks very much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). You’re stuck in believing that some concurrency issue was the reason for your performance problem while, as explained, differences in execution times are quite normal for a lot of algorithms (but you refuse to even discuss what algorithm are involved). Why should it be a problem that all threads switch to RUNNING at once? That’s the very purpose of threads, to be able to run concurrently. 24 running threads on 40 cores should not cause any problem.